# gcc not finding files in dir specified with -I

Tags: c, gcc

I need to include some platform specific jni files in the following dir:

```
$ ls -l /home/ubuntu/jdk8/include/linux
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 995 Mar 15 09:00 jawt_md.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 824 Mar 15 09:00 jni_md.h
```

So the `gcc` command was appropriately (?) augmented:

```
gcc -I"/home/ubuntu/jdk8/include/linux" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" ..
```

But the files inside the `linux` subdir are not found:

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '"/home/ubuntu/jdk8/include/linux"' '-I' '/home/ubuntu/jdk8/include' ..


/home/ubuntu/jdk8/include/jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
```

So what needs to be tweaked here? If it matters this is on `ubuntu`16.0.4` and

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

**Update**  Here is the inclusion statement in `jni.h`

```
#include "jni_md.h"
```

Now how can they expect that to be found - should it not be

```
#include <jni_md.h>
```

**Update on the update** Per `Arkadiusz Drabczyk` and a link he provided http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html  they should both be OK. In fact the behavior appears to be the same.

**Note** if I copy the files under `include/linux/*.h` to the parent `include` dir the compilation work: so the ***only*** problem is the include path.

***YAU*** (Yet another update)  Per Arkadiusz I tried out `clang`:  same error.

Comment: What you say are the arguments to gcc and what gcc reports are different. Please verify the precise arguments you are providing.

Comment: @rici How are they different?  The only thing i can see here is the `$JAVA_HOME` being translated by bash to `/home/ubuntu/jdk8`

Comment: @javadba: Could you use `clang` instead and see if it works? Or another version of `gcc`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  This is on ubuntu - so no `clang` at least by default?

Comment: It may not be installed by default but I believe a single `apt-get install` should do the job?

Comment: I think that `"` and `<>` should not matter here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  Thx I did try the other way and same problem.  I will install/try out clang.  Are options the same for it?

Comment: Yes, they should be the same. Just replace `gcc` with `clang`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)`  same result

Comment: @javadba: the literal quotes on the first path, according to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the *order of the options* was messing up: I had

```
-I<something> -odmaserver.so  -I<something else>
```

It needs to be

```
-I<something> -I<something else>  -odmaserver.so
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but unlikely, that it needs a trailing slash on the directory string. Is jni.h including <jni_md.h> or "jni_md.h" ??

Comment: Trailing slashes are never needed in `-I` options. The difference between `<>` and `""` header names is solely the default search path.